# Can't uninstall Python 2.7.9 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, python, uninstall

Hello I am trying to uninstall Python 2.7.9 on Windows 10, but this pop-up keeps showing up:

There is a problem with this Windows Install package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I tried to repair it using the Python 2.7.9 Setup, but it says:

The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.
Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package "target.msi" in the box below.

I tried to look for it in the AppData\Local\Temp\ but I can't seem to find any target.msi files.

Is there any way to uninstall Python 2.7.9? Thanks

Comment: Windows requires the same `.msi` file (same version) for uninstalling as was used for installing. In your case it would seem that it can't be found, and thus Windows is requesting you to point it the the correct file (this is what it is waiting for with the file selection dialog with "target.msi"). If you have the `.msi` file for Python 2.7.9 you should provide the path to that file as the "alternate path to a folder containing the installation package".

Answer (score 1):

Download the Python 2.7.9 MSI again and use that to uninstall. You *may* need to do a "repair" first.